# Pointwise convergence in Lawvere metric spaces

Tags: ct.category-theory, mg.metric-geometry, limits-and-convergence, enriched-category-theory, function-spaces

In the formalism of [Lawvere metric spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metric+space#LawvereMetricSpace), we have that the distance in the hom-space $[X,Y]$ is given by:
$$
d(f,g) = \sup_{x\in X} d(f(x),g(x)) .
$$ 
Therefore, a sequence of functions $f_n:X\to Y$ converges to $f:X\to Y$ in $[X,Y]$ if and only if it converges uniformly.

How can we talk about *pointwise* convergence in this setting, instead?

Comment: What is stopping you from saying "for all $x$, $f_n(x)$ converges"? Or in other words, for all morphism $\top \to X$, the sequence of composites $\top \to X \to Y$ converges (uniformly)?

Comment: @skysurf3000 Nothing, of course. I just wonder if there is a different way, less "set-like".